# I can't fetch anything else than '1' to my PDO query

Tags: database

Here is my PDO request :

```
$query = db_select('review_ratings_table')
   ->fields('review_ratings_table',array('review_nid'))
   ->condition('loc_id', $loc_id, 'LIKE')
   ->condition('user_id', $user_id, 'LIKE')
   ->condition('valid', '1', '=')
   ->execute();
while($record = $query->fetchAssoc()) {
 drupal_set_message('<pre>test '.print_r($record).'</pre>');
}
```

I have tried many ways to get the result of this request (fetchAll, fetchField, fetchAssoc ...) and I keep printing "1" instead of the review_nid or anything else.

Thanks for you help.

Will

=> Hi,
If I use dvm($query) I get that :

> DatabaseStatementBase::__set_state(array(
>      'dbh' => 
>     DatabaseConnection_mysql::__set_state(array(
>        'needsCleanup' => false,
>        'target' => 'default',
>        'key' => 'default',
>        'logger' => NULL,
>        'transactionLayers' => 
>       array (
>         'drupal_transaction' => 'drupal_transaction',
>       ),
>        'driverClasses' => 
>       array (
>         'SelectQuery' => 'SelectQuery',
>         'DatabaseTransaction' => 'DatabaseTransaction',
>       ),
>        'statementClass' => 'DatabaseStatementBase',
>        'transactionSupport' => true,
>        'transactionalDDLSupport' => false,
>        'temporaryNameIndex' => 0,
>        'connectionOptions' => 
>       array (
>         'database' => '*******',
>         'username' => '*******',
>         'password' => '*******',
>         'host' => 'localhost',
>         'port' => '3306',
>         'driver' => 'mysql',
>         'prefix' => 
>         array (
>           'default' => '',
>         ),
>       ),
>        'schema' => NULL,
>        'prefixes' => 
>       array (
>         'default' => '',
>       ),
>        'prefixSearch' => 
>       array (
>         0 => '{',
>         1 => '}',
>       ),
>        'prefixReplace' => 
>       array (
>         0 => '',
>         1 => '',
>       ),
>     )),
>      'queryString' => 'SELECT review_ratings_table.review_nid AS review_nid
>   FROM 
>   review_ratings_table review_ratings_table
>   WHERE  (loc_id LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE \'\\\') AND (user_id = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (valid = :db_condition_placeholder_2) ',
>   ))

and

> Error message
>   Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DatabaseStatementBase could not be converted to string in review_ratings_table_node_presave() (line 52 of C:\Bitnami\drupal-7\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\custom\review_ratings_table\review_ratings_table.module).

and

dvm($query->fetchAssoc()); gives me that

> array(
>     'review_nid' => '2',
>   )

Which is what I want but I don't know how to access it.

Thanks

Comment: What's in `$loc_id` and `$user_id`, and why are you using `LIKE` for (what I assume is) a numeric field? It'd be a good idea to try your query in raw SQL first to make sure that logic is sound

Comment: Hi Clive, $loc_id is a string an $user_id an integer. I have tried with a raw SQL and I got the same result unfortunately. I have also tried without any conditions and it was the same. Thanks

Comment: what are the results of `dvm($query);` and  `dvm($query->fetchAssoc());`? If it doesn't show anything then try with `var_dump()` also...

Comment: Hi  Jhilke Dai I have added the result of dvm($query); into my original question. I don't know why but var_dump gives me an empty result. thanks

Comment: Following your latest edit, ``$result = $query->fetchAssoc(); return $result[0]['review_nid'];``

Comment: Hi Ben, it would seem logical but I have already tried and it's not working. thanks

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: $result = $query->fetchAssoc(); return $result['review_nid']; thanks this was the solution sorry for the belated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `drupal_set_message('<pre>test '.print_r($record).'</pre>');` you're putting the return value of [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) into a string, not printing the contents of `$record`.

You can acccess the value you need with:

```
$result = $query->fetchAssoc();

// make sure we found something
if (empty($result) || empty($result[0]['review_nid'])) {
  dpm("No result");      
}

// load the noad we found
$node = node_load($nid)
dpm($node);
```

Comment: Hi Ben, what do you mean by "do something with the nid"? I would need be able to display at least for testing purpose. thanks

Comment: Added more code above but, really, as long as you use `print_r` correctly in your original code you're good to go.